# How to time stamp more than one cell on Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

In my Gooogle sheet document at the moment is have 4 cells that regularly get updated. Each time these are updated i want to time stamp a separate cell.

I can get the attached script to work for 1 cell but when i duplicate the script to get it working for another cell it stops the earlier one from working.

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT+1";
  var timestamp_format = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"; 
  var updateColName = "Development Team Comments";
  var timeStampColName = "To update select cell";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('WIP'); 


  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { 
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

I have also tried this code which doesn't seem to work for the subsequent cells:

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT+1";
  var timestamp_format = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "Development Team Comments";
  var timeStampColName = "To update select cell";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('WIP'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.

  var responseArray = ["o update select cell", "Bupa time stamp","Date Stamp Move Live"];
  var questionArray = ["Development Team Comments", "BDC proofing comments", "Approved Y"];


  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

What i expect i should be able to do is to be able to update any of the cells and for them to present the current time as the script above does. Do i need to duplicate this or is there a way of inserting in the cell references.

Comment: Which columns are the editable cells in and where do you want the timestamps to be set?

Comment: Editable are the ones listed next to question array and where the timestamp should be are listed against the answer array

Comment: So all you need is a script to write a timestamp in a different column every time a cell is edited? For example: if column A is edited, timestamp column D, if column B is edited, timestamp column E.

Comment: @ross yess this is correct

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your script is pretty complicated for what you actually need, it's checking all of the headers etc when really all you need is a few `setValue()` based on `if` statements, throw this inside an `onEdit(e)` trigger and you're done!

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('WIP');
  var timezone = 'GMT+1';
  var format = 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss';

  var cell = e.range;
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var col = cell.getColumn();

  var stamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, format);

  if (col === 1) {                          //if edited cell is in column A
    sheet.getRange(row, 4).setValue(stamp); //set timestamp in column D
  }
  if (col === 2) {                          //if edited cell is in column B
    sheet.getRange(row, 5).setValue(stamp); //set timestamp in column E    
  }
  if (col === 3) {                          //if edited cell is in column C
    sheet.getRange(row, 6).setValue(stamp); //set timestamp in column F
  }
}
```

This script will work up to column C, if you want to add more you can just adjust the numbers in the `if` statements and `getRange()` to fit your requirements.